# Alternative to nested functions in C?

Tags: c, nested-function

What is the standard alternative to nested functions in C? How do I give one function the scope of another function? I don't really want to pass around extra parameters like a struct, use variable length input, or use the gcc extension unless there is no other way.

For my specific problem, I have this function:

```
double findroot(double (*fp)(double), double start, double end);
```

It finds the root of a function, f(x), of one variable with a function pointer as an argument.

I want to pass in a function of multiple variables where all but one are fixed. For example, f(x,a,b,c), where a, b, and c are all constants that are passed in and x is the only variable that changes. How do I find f(0,a,b,c) while keeping the findroot function the same so that the findroot function is reusable and generic and not specific to this one case?

Thanks.

Comment: So, your question boils down to: What is the alternative if all possibilities (except excessive use of globals, which is an evil unto itself) are ruled out beforehand. Did I get that right?

Comment: I disagree with your design. In all functions I write in C that accept callbacks, I _always_ also accept a `void*` pointer, and make the callback accept that pointer as its first parameter. This promotes good software engineering principles by allowing the functions to be reentrant; In particular this avoids use of out-of-band data read through globals. For instance: `typedef double (*SINGLEVARFN)(void* ctx, double x);  double findRoot(SINGLEVARFN fn, void* ctx, double start, double end);`

Comment: A lambda with capture but C++ serves your request.

Comment: So the answer is to use globals or one of the three options I mentioned? What about using a macro? I am just trying to figure out the standard solution to this problem.

Comment: @user1801359 The (should-be) standard solution is to always allow callbacks to accept a "private" pointer, to pass both the callback and the private pointer to the function that uses the callback, and to invoke the callback with the provided private pointer. Are you familiar with `pthread_create()`? It is a _model_ example of how this is done properly.

Comment: Another standard would be to figure out if `findroot` is capable of doing this to begin with. If its environment is reset/reinitilized with each set of roots, it may make no sense.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thanks. I was about to ask for a simple example. I am not familiar with pthread_create() but I will look into it.

Comment: @user1801359 `pthread_create()` is the function that spawns a thread in Unix. Its arguments are pointers to the `pthread_t` and `pthread_attr_t` attributes objects, a pointer to a callback `void* (*) (void*)` and an argument pointer `void*` for the callback. When the new thread is spawned, it calls the callback with the `void*` argument provided to `pthread_create()`. The callback is designed such that it accepts precisely that argument, and thus thread spawning does not require any global state or nested functions.

Comment: @user1801359 commented : *"What about using a macro? I am just trying to figure out the standard solution to this problem."*  Your problem is perhaps that you perceive it as a problem. Using a macro is certainly worse than your perceived problem!  You appear to be asking a question about what you think is a solution to some other problem which is itself not clearly explained. Try asking a question about the root issue rather than an unimplementable solution.

Comment: I am not sure how the (unclearly stated) problem suggest nested functions as a solution.

Comment: The comments suggesting using a callback that accepts a single void pointer as its only argument still have drawbacks. They require you either structure your functions in a very specific way or use nested functions. I think if a single argument could be used easily, this wouldn't be a question. However, the tradeoffs should be accepted. These solutions are elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find f(x,a,b,c) where a, b and c are invariant, then that suggests a new more specialised function f2(x) = f(x,a,b,c).  For example:

```
double f2( double x )
{    
    return f( x, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ) ;
}
```